# Mean regression factor scores and attributes cross tabulation yields. Why are all expected signs reversed?

Tags: spss, categorical-data, factor-analysis, regression-coefficients, contingency-tables

I ran a factor analysis on 20 reasons for purchasing 4 different goods. These are ranked on a Likert scale from 1 to 5 with 5 being "extremely important", 4 "important", etc.

I extracted 4 factors which I am able to label based on the group of reasons that loaded well into each of these factors. I saved these factors as regression factor scores in SPSS. Then I did a cross-tabulation with each of the goods as rows and regression factor scores as columns. I used the mean for the regression factor scores. I expected the sign of the factor score and each of the goods to be positive if there was a relationship with that factor score, or negative otherwise.

However, the signs are exactly reversed. So for those goods that I thought would have the highest positive mean factor score, I am actually getting the highest negative, etc. Am I completely wrong in the approach I am taking to 
cross-tabulate this, or am I interpreting these wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The sign of factors is essentially arbitrary. You can just as easily get a factor for "tallness" as one for "shortness", so check the loadings of the items on the factors.

But how are you using scores in a crosstabulation? Factor scores are continuous variables. They should be treated as such.

Comment: I am using regression factor scores against the four types of goods in a cross tabulation. I am selecting the mean of the regression factor score variables against these.

Comment: I don't understand. If you have a crosstabulation, then one categorical variable goes on one side and another categorical variable goes on the other side. What are your two variables?

Comment: I am putting the goods variable on the rows and each of the 4 regression factor scores on the columns. It is a 4 x 4 matrix. Custom table in SPSS. So one categorical var in the row and 4 vars on the columns.

Comment: Regression factor scores are NOT categorical.

Comment: Can you then comment intuitively how would I interpret the relationship between a respondent's factor score and his choice on the good, which is my variable of interest with 4 possibilities? I am trying to learn the proper interpretation of respondent's factor scores as these random numbers mean little to me by itself so I need to find a way of relating them to my dependent variable. My goal is to eventually use them in a multinomial logit, but I can't do that without a proper understanding of the scores themselves.

Comment: Multinomial logit is correct. You interpret the factor scores from the loadings and other output of the factor analysis itself.